# How to rollback delete command without using transaction

Tags: sql-server-2012, truncate

How to rollback delete command without using transaction  ? if we can't , then what's the difference between Truncate & delete ?

Comment: Which Platform are we talking about here?

Comment: not enough informations given.

Comment: am writing the code in SQL Server 2012  .

Answer (score 4):

You cannot rollback in this case, but when you are using the **Full Recovery Model**, then you can turn your database back to the moment before you issued the delete command.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot `ROLLBACK` an operation without a transaction. You could probably use [implicit transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx), but you still need to call `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` explicitly. However, for better control, it's better to wrap the statement(s) in a `BEGIN TRANSACTION...COMMIT / ROLLBACK` block anyway. This way you'll avoid any confusion and the need to use the `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTION` setting.

Answer (score 2):

You can roll back DELETE or TRUNCATE (and most other operations) if and only if they are part of a transaction that's not yet committed. Alternatively you could restore the deleted/truncated data from a backup.

There are several differences between TRUNCATE and DELETE. Most notably TRUNCATE can only empty a table whereas DELETE deletes just the rows you specify. TRUNCATE deallocates and logs data at the page level instead of row level, which typically makes TRUNCATE a more efficient method than DELETE for deleting the entire content of a table.

Comment: If he is using a **full recovery model**, then he could turn back the database to the moment before the delete command was issued.